# Creating a new column based on condition of an index

Tags: python, pandas

I have df:

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo']),
       np.array(['one','two'] * 9),
        np.array([1,2,3] * 6)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(18,2), index=arrays)


                      col0      col1
bar one     1   0.872359    -1.115871
    two     2   -0.937908   -0.528563
    one     3   -0.118874   0.286595
    two     1   -0.507698   1.364643
    one     2   1.507611    1.379498
    two     3   -1.398019   -1.603056
baz one     1   1.498263    0.412380
    two     2   -0.930022   -1.483657
    one     3   -0.438157   1.465089
    two     1   0.161887    1.346587
    one     2   0.167086    1.246322
    two     3   0.276344    -1.206415
foo one     1   -0.045389   -0.759927
    two     2   0.087999    -0.435753
    one     3   -0.232054   -2.221466
    two     1   -1.299483   1.697065
    one     2   0.612211    -1.076738
    two     3   -1.482573   0.907826
```

And now I want to create 'NEW' column that:

```
for 'bar'
  if index.level(2) > 1
     "NEW" = col1
  else
     "NEW" = col2
```

for 'baz' the same with >2

for 'foo' the same with >3

How to do it without Py loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) for select index values by levels and then for new column [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
#if possible use dictionary
d = {'bar':1, 'baz':2, 'foo':3}
m = df.index.get_level_values(2)  > df.rename(d).index.get_level_values(0)

df['NEW'] = np.where(m, df.col1, df.col2)
```

For more general solution use[`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
a = df.index.get_level_values(2) 
b = df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series().rank(method='dense')

df['NEW'] = np.where(a > b, df.col1, df.col2)
```

Detail:

```
print (b)
bar    1.0
bar    1.0
bar    1.0
bar    1.0
bar    1.0
bar    1.0
baz    2.0
baz    2.0
baz    2.0
baz    2.0
baz    2.0
baz    2.0
foo    3.0
foo    3.0
foo    3.0
foo    3.0
foo    3.0
foo    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes, but how to deal with first index? It is  > 1 only for 'bar'.

Comment: Thanks for update, thats something. I guess I still have to loop through all values in index(level=0).

Comment: I want to avoid looping - I have huge databases. I have another df1 with values for each value in df.level(0). It has simple index, the same as df.index.level(0). bar- 1, baz - 2 , foo - 3 etc.

Comment: When I use 'select' for baz values  previously calculated values for bar are overwritten with NaN. I guess I will have to slice df by level(0) and then put everything together.

Comment: OK, so sorry, I missed last part of your question. Now it working prefectly!

Comment: Thank you. This should work too. I spend so much time on this... I will try to implement both methods and compare speed. Will come back later. Thanks again.

Comment: I will go with this method (df1.todict()). It is slightly faster and I understand it better. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can avoid looping over df.level(0) by using `df.factorize`:

```
In [40]: thresh = pd.factorize(df.index.get_level_values(0).values)[0] + 1

In [41]: mask = df.index.get_level_values(2) > thresh

In [42]: df['NEW'] = np.where(mask, df.col1, df.col2)

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
               col1      col2       NEW
bar one 1  0.247222 -0.270104 -0.270104
    two 2  0.429196 -1.385352  0.429196
    one 3  0.782293 -1.565623  0.782293
    two 1  0.392214  1.023960  1.023960
    one 2 -1.628410 -0.484275 -1.628410
    two 3  0.256757  0.529373  0.256757
baz one 1 -0.568608 -0.776577 -0.776577
    two 2  2.142408 -0.815413 -0.815413
    one 3  0.860080  0.501965  0.860080
    two 1 -0.267029 -0.025360 -0.025360
    one 2  0.187145 -0.063436 -0.063436
    two 3  0.351296 -2.050649  0.351296
foo one 1  0.704941  0.176698  0.176698
    two 2 -0.380353  1.027745  1.027745
    one 3 -1.337364 -0.568359 -0.568359
    two 1 -0.588601 -0.800426 -0.800426
    one 2  1.513358 -0.616237 -0.616237
    two 3  0.244831  1.027109  1.027109
```

Comment: I have no idea how this works :) but it does what expected. Now, all I have to do is to replace 'thresh' with my list from df1. Thanks.